# how to connection aws redis with c#

Tags: c#, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

how to use c# to connection aws redis ?

I create aws redis done and create linux host to conntection redis is successed,

but when I use c# code to connection, I get failed.

```
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("test.qzgpeh.ng.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379,abortConnect=false");
    });

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
```

Error Message

> No connection is active/available to service this operation: GET hello; UnableToConnect on test.qzgpeh.ng.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 5s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: HAUSER, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=12,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=0,Free=32767,Min=12,Max=32767), v: 2.1.58.34321

how I can to fix it ?

Comment: You should post the error message as well.

Comment: ok, plz check new post

Comment: Does your redis server use TLS? If so, you need to tell it that in the config string. It may also be worth specifying the TLS version, since that has been a big pain point (in IT generally, not specifically this context) for the last few months. If you don't want to guess / lookup the config string keys, you can use the `ConfigurationOptions` API which gives you an object model with properties to play with.

Comment: Also, a good debugging trick for connection problems is to pass a `TextWriter` as the optional `log` parameter. You may get a much more detailed output that way. I'm guessing your server also needs a password? (Again, on the configuration string or `ConfigurationOptions` object)

Answer (score 0):

Posting if someone facing a similar issue.

I was trying to access Redis data from the Elastic Beanstalk .Net application and facing a similar issue.

In my case, it was an issue from a security group. I followed the below steps

1. Create my VPC and Subnet and Security Group
2. Create and deploy an application in EBS.
3. Create a security group (for Redis) and allow connection from EBS Security group
4. Create Redis in same VPC and Security group (step 3 security group)
5. Able to access Redis from .Net application

Redis Security Group Inbound Rule

[image]

.NET Core Sample Code

```
public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<PrivacyModel> _logger;
    private readonly IDatabase cache;
    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("******-redis-cache.yq8meb.0001.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379,abortConnect=false");
    });

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }

    public PrivacyModel(ILogger<PrivacyModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        this.cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        StartTime = this.cache.StringGet("StartTime");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StartTime))
        {
            StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            this.cache.StringSet("StartTime", StartTime);
        }
    }
}
```